# cats' NonEmptyList vs scala stdlib ::

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I am studying the cats library recently, and I have come across this class called `NonEmptyList`.

After reading the api, I couldn't help wondering what is it that made the cats authors to create a new class, instead of utilizing something that is built in (`::`) and use type classes to extend it. It is not even listed in the cats github page, so I have come here to ask about it. Maybe it is because cons is a subtype of `List`? (Though I do not know the implications of it)

What are the differences between `::` and `NEL`? And why did cats authors have to write `NEL` instead of using `::`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main reason for having `NonEmptyList` which doesn't extend from `List` is *developer experience* of including assumptions in the APIs.

Firstly, note that `::` has all the methods `List` has which can be misleading and it makes it harder to design better APIs with more powerful assumptions. Additionally, `List` doesn't have any methods that directly return `::`, which means that developer needs to maintain *non-empty* abstraction manually.

Let me show you an example which shows what I mean in practice:

```scala
// NonEmptyList usage is intuitive and types fit together nicely
val nonEmpty: NonEmptyList[Int] = NonEmptyList.of(1, 2, 3)
val biggerNonEmpty: NonEmptyList[Int] = 0 :: nonEmpty
val nonEmptyMapped: NonEmptyList[Int] = nonEmpty.map(_ * 2)

// :: has lots of problems
// PROBLEM: we can't easily instantiate ::
val cons: ::[Int] = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil // type mismatch; found: List[Int]; required: ::[Int]
val cons: ::[Int] = new ::[Int](1, ::(2, ::(3, Nil)))

// PROBLEM: adding new element to Cons returns List
val biggerCons: ::[Int] = 0 :: cons // type mismatch; found: List[Int]; required: ::[Int]

// PROBLEM: ::.map returns List
val consMapped : ::[Int] = cons.map(_ * 2) // type mismatch; found: List[Int]; required: ::[Int]
```

Note that `NonEmptyList` has methods that return `List`, namely `filter`, `filterNot` and `collect`. Why? Because filtering through `NonEmptyList` may mean that you filter out all elements and the list can become an empty one.

This is what makes the whole *non-empty* abstraction so powerful. By properly using function input and output types, you can encode assumptions about the API. `::` doesn't provide this abstraction.